# Recovering Mongodb collections and documents data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

good day to you all.

### I am currently having a hard time restoring the MongoDB database.
Here is what happened.

Thanks for looking into this matter
Basically, my server and MongoDB 3.2 server running on DigitalOcean.
I made some changes on mongod.conf file to allow remote access from my local machine. Since then, it no longer worked. I got Mongodb connection failed issue so reinstalled new Mongodb version 4.4 and it doesn't want to load existing data which is located in var/lib/MongoDB. So I downloaded the whole data files as posted above on my local machine.

Now, at least I want to open the current database on my local machine but I couldn't find any proper way to achieve this.  Thanks again for looking into this issue.

[image]

Comment: What MongoDB Version is this? How were these files captured? Do you have the original startup configuration parameters? They will need to be the same if you want to start it up.

Comment: Also, it would be best to provide as much information as possible. First, I would take another copy of this data so you always have a local hard copy. Next, provide any information from your current mongo logs. What did you do to "ruin" the server. And what do you mean by "it no longer opens"?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this matter.Basically, my server runs on DigitalOcean.

Comment: If the files were from a MongoDB 3.2 deployment, then you'll be best using MongoDB 3.2 to run using the files. Also, try using your old configuration to see if it runs. If you want to upgrade to 4.4, then you'll need to stage through all of the major deployments - 3.4, 3.6, 4.0, 4.2, then 4.4.